# Optimization problem on the space of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $p>1.$ Define the set

$$C=\left\{\mu=\{\mu_n\}_{n=0}^\infty: \{\mu_n\}\subseteq (0,1), \;\{\mu_n\} \textrm{ decreasing, } \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu_n(n+1)^p =1\right\}.$$

Determine $$\inf_{\mu\in C}\; \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu_n(n+1).$$

This problem arises when we try to find a  sharp upper bound on the dual norm of the derivative of the penalty function in the Borwein-Preiss Variational Principle. I tried to use Chebyshev inequality(after a transformation), but unsuccessfully obtained the trivial bound $inf\geq 0$. If you find a lower bound, I will be happy too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inf is $0$. Let $k \ge 1$ and $\epsilon_k = \frac{1}{1^p+2^p+\dots+k^p}$. Take $\mu_n = \epsilon_k$ for $0 \le n \le k-1$, and $\mu_n = 0$ for $n \ge k$. Then, $\mu \in C$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu_n(n+1) = \frac{1+2+\dots+k}{1^p+2^p+\dots+k^p}$. This goes to $0$ as $k \to \infty$ (since $p > 1$).

Comment: Note that  $\mu \notin C$ because $\mu_n=0$ for $n\geq k.$ It is a good idea nevertheless. I think we could modify it. thanks

Comment: It can easily be modified. Just modify $\mu$ a bit to be extremely close to $0$ after $k$.